# Why did I win "Asia Passport" achievement early?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, online, ticket-to-ride-asia

I'm playing iPad edition. Fifth Legendary Asia achievement says:

*Asia Passport: Win all achievements for the Legendary Asia map.*

I thought it means that I have to win first four achievements.

For some reason I won it in the middle of the next game after winning Mountain Hermit. At that point I already had Double Trouble, but not two others.

Any ideas what happened?

Comment: This happened to me too - I'm fairly sure it's just a bug.

Comment: As stated you should never be able to win it, as it is a Legendary Asia achievement and so you need to have it in order to earn it!

Comment: @TimothyJones Thanks, I've sent this question to the Days of Wonder support.

Comment: @Nick I don't understand what you are saying, sorry.

Comment: @Sergii It itself is a legendary Asia map achievement, so in order to obtain you, you must first have it! It should say "Win all OTHER achievements for the Legendary Asia map". But that's just being pedantic really.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while this can be considered on topic since it is a computer-based game based off a board game it does not appear to be on topic. What you are describing sounds like a bug in the game you are playing and something that should be reported to the developer and it is not something that anyone on this stack exchange site can help you with.

Comment: should this be moved to [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @chicks this question is to old to be migrated but there is nothing stopping it from being asked there. However this is a question that is asking about a bug so there is nothing that a user at Arqade could answer about it.